# Share both image and text using share intent

Tags: android, android-intent, share

Hi i want to share image and also text together i used following code but it's only sharing image, text is not being shared,

```
private void shareIntent(){
    String imagePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + "/logo.jpg";
    Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);    
    sharingIntent.setType("*/*");    
    sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "www.google.co.in");
    sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(new File(imagePath)));
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share Image!"));
}
```

How can i share both text and image ?? please help.

Comment: have you tried with `ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE`

Answer (score 0):

```
private void shareIntent(){
    String imagePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + "/logo.jpg";
    Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);    
    sharingIntent.setType("*/*");    
    sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "www.google.co.in");
sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "www.google.co.in");
    sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(new File(imagePath)));
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share Image!"));
}
```

Comment: sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "www.google.co.in");

Comment: not working, for whatsApp it only shares image, text is not being shared

Comment: WhatsApp not share text with image

Comment: isn't there any way if i want to do that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60500/discussion-between-rajesh-suthar-and-daxeshkhatri).

Answer (score 0):

```
private void initShareIntent(String _text)
{
    File filePath = getFileStreamPath("shareimage.jpg");  //optional //internal storage
    Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
    shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, _text);
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,Uri.fromFile(new File(filePath.toString()))); 
    //optional//use this when you want to send an image
    shareIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
    shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "send"));
}
```